# `npx mrm@2 lint-staged` crashes with `Error: .git can't be found (...)`

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, husky, lint-staged

I am trying to set up lint-staged following the instructions from the [prettier documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html#option-1-lint-stagedhttpsgithubcomokonetlint-staged).
When I run `npx mrm@2 lint-staged`, I get the following error:

```
Error: .git can't be found (see https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory)
    at Object.install (/home/moritz/.npm/_npx/51762936ba23ccdb/node_modules/husky/lib/index.js:20:15)
    at task (/home/moritz/.npm/_npx/51762936ba23ccdb/node_modules/mrm-task-lint-staged/index.js:214:8)
    at /home/moritz/.npm/_npx/51762936ba23ccdb/node_modules/mrm/src/index.js:170:20
```

I followed the [link](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory) from the error and changed the scripts section in `package.json` accordingly.

```
 "scripts": {
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install laravel/.husky"
  }
```

I still get the same error when running `npx mrm@2 lint-staged`.
What can I do to get lint-staged running?

My project structure:

```
project
│   .git    
└───laravel
    │   package.json
```

Comment: `cd ..` might be moving the cwd to a folder which is not in a git repo?

Comment: I run `npx mrm@2 lint-staged` inside the `laravel` folder and the `package.json` is also located there. So I think `cd ..` should move the cwd to `project`, which is the root of the git repo. Or am I missing something?

Comment: *Git* hooks always start in the root of the repository. *Husky* may or may not do something different, though judging from the link you included, it looks like "does not do something different" is correct and therefore `cd ..` would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> So I think cd .. should move the cwd to project, which is the root of the git repo.

Simply add `pwd && cd .. && husky...`.
That way, you will know for sure from where you are starting from.

Comment: I do not receive any output other than the error. To check whether it is actually the prepare script what's crashing i added `touch /tmp/i_ran && cd.. (...)` and it seems prepare is not even running.

Comment: @MoritzGottschling OK, so the error is not from the execution of any husky command then.